# How to exclude occurrence of a substring from a string using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string input in the following two forms.

1.

```
<!--XYZdfdjf., 15456, hdfv.4002-->
<!DOCTYPE
```

2.

```
<!--XYZdfdjf., 15456, hdfv.4002
<!DOCTYPE
```

I want to return a match if the form 2 is encountered and no match for the form 1.
Thus basically I want a regex that accepts arbitrarily all characters between `<!--` and `<!DOCTYPE`, except when there is an occurance of `-->` in between.

I am using Pattern , Matcher and java regex.
Help is sought in terms of a regex specifically usable with Pattern.compile()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)<!--(?:(?!-->).)*<!DOCTYPE");
```

`(?:(?!-->).)*` matches one character at a time, *after* checking that it's not the first character of `-->`.

`(?s)` sets DOTALL mode (a.k.a. single-line mode), allowing the `.` to match newline characters.

If there's a possibility of two or more matches and you want to find them individually, you can replace the `*` with a non-greedy `*?`, like so:

```
"(?s)<!--(?:(?!-->).)*?<!DOCTYPE"
```

For example, applying that regex to the text of your question will find two matches, while the original regex will find one, longer match.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like it is easily solved by using `String.contains()`:

```
if (yourHtml.contains("-->")) {
    // exclude
} else {
    // extract the content you need
    String content = 
        yourHtml.substring("<!--".length(), yourHtml.indexOf("<!DOCTYPE"));
}
```

I think you are looking too far into it.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution, but I was looking for a regex solution, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
\<!--([\s\S](?!--\>))*?(?=\<\!DOCTYPE)
```

this uses a negative lookahead to prevent the **-->**  and a positive lookahead to find the **<!DOCTYPE**
Here's a good reference for [atomic assertions (lookahead and behind)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. This too works for me. Just that in Java String we have to use \\ instead of \ to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a testing system handy so i can't give you the regex but you should look inside the Pattern documentation for something called `negative lookahead assertion`. This allows you to express rules of the form: Match this if not followed by that.

It should help you :)

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression might not be the best answer to your problem. Have you tried splitting the first line away from everything else and seeing if it contains the `-->`?

Specifically, something like:

```
String htmlString;
String firstLine = htmlString.split("\r?\n")[0];
if(firstLine.contains("-->"))
    ;//no match
//match
```